# Is there a way, in Django, to define routes using Flask-style route syntax?

Tags: python, django

Setting aside any strongly-held feelings about Django vs Flask, I have a *whole bunch* of Flask-style routes I'd like to convert to Django. They look like your usual Flask routes:

```
'/foo/<spam>/<int:eggs>/'
```

This gets even more complex with converters in Flask like `path`:

```
'/foo/<path:location>'
```

So I have all of these routes, and I'd rather not try to figure out regular expressions that approximate them in converting my views. I'm looking to just parse the Flask-style routes in Django. Is there a way to use Flask-style route patterns in Django?

Comment: Try read this from the https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/urls, and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/translation/#url-internationalization, but maybe it's better to use native `django` URL routing like @alecxe suggest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have not personally used it, but this sounds exactly what you are asking about - [`django-fsu`](https://github.com/afg984/django-fsu):

> Flask-Style URL Patterns for Django

I would though still try to stick to Django URL-routing style and avoid "transitional" solutions like this. You can also use `django-fsu` temporarily to migrate, then cover all the endpoints with end-to-end and functional tests and, then, once you have the coverage, migrate to the Django native URL routing style.